# Is there a way to filter a list, find a specific item and replace it with a list in the same lambda?

Tags: kotlin, filter, lambda

I am trying to enhance a lambda expression which is currently filtering out on a specific property of the List of items and then maps over filtered list to return a List. This is the expected return type. I am now trying to find if a specific value exists in the return type (List) and replace it with another list. I have tried using any/contains but I lose access to the original list. Is it even possible to do all this in the same lambda?
This is the current lambda:

```
val primaryUsers = usersList
        .filter { it.primaryUserGroups.any { userId -> userIds.contains(userId) } }
        .map { it.username }
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you're describing without seeing your code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 updated to show current code.

Comment: Like Tenfour04 said, let's see even more.  What is the type of `usersList`? and was inside one of those Users? presumably collection of `userId`s and a `username` ?
To roughly answer your question, the answer is probably yes, but you will need to use a `map` operation since that has an input and output, whereas the only output from a `filter` is boolean